# Browser hangs when parsing dates

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

I've succeeded in getting this visualization (small multiples of stacked area charts) to work, in slightly different form, when I use dummy data for the dates, i.e. when I use only years. However, when I use actual dates like this, it's problematic:

```
Record,Code,2008-1-1,2008-2-1,2008-3-1,2008-4-1,2008-5-1,2008-6-1,2008-7-1...
```

instead of this dummy data, which works fine

```
Record,Code,1895,1896,1897,1898,1899,1900,1901...
```

When I use full dates, the browser hangs; there is no error message. I've fixed parsing errors before, but this one seems beyond my abilities.

Here's the non-working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fOlpxo648OyCSM7Sq8ak?p=preview
Another Plunker, one which actually loads, but which uses dummy data, is at the bottom of this question.

This piece of code seems particularly problematic:

```
function createDatesArr(start, end) {
var arr = [];
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++ ) {
    arr.push((i));  //      arr.push(String(i));
}
return arr;
}
```

In slightly different form, I'll get an error message that "dates" has not been defined. I've tried to solve this with the following code:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
var startDate = new Date('2008-1-1');
var endDate = new Date ('2017-12-1');
var dates = createDatesArr(startDate, endDate);
```

Or like so:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
var startYear = "2008-1-1";
var endYear = "2017-12-1";
var dates = createYearsArr(startYear, endYear);
```

Or like this:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
var startDate = d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d.Date; });
var endDate = d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.Date; });
var dates = createDatesArr(startDate, endDate);
```

Or, alternatively, by defining "dates" like so:

```
d3.csv(dataPath, function(data) {
    var dates = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
    data = data.filter(function(d) {
            return true;
    });
    var dates = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
```

None of this has worked, but I'm hopeful someone can help me fix this.

Here's another Plunker, that actually works, which demonstrates what I'm ultimately trying to achieve, albeit using dummy data (years only) for dates: http://plnkr.co/edit/jRC8iQg2kdtlZWtGE020?p=preview

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, your problem in this code

```
function createDatesArr(start, end) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++ ) {
    arr.push((i));  //      arr.push(String(i));
  }
  return arr;
}
```

More precisely here - `i++`;

Look at pic below, variable `i` it is a date as milliseconds. You increase it by one millisecond after each loop iteration. But step between your data points as I can see it is a month.

`Record,Code,2008-1-1,2008-2-1,2008-3-1,2008-4-1,2008-5-1,2008-6-1,2008-7-1...`

[image]

So you should increase `i` by one month after each loop iteration to solve your problem.

You can do it with [`d3.time.month.offset`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_offset):

```
for (var i = start; i <= end; i = d3.time.month.offset(i, 1)) {
  arr.push((i));
}
```

After that, you should remove `dateFormat(...)` because data item it is exactly valid javascript date and rewrites `transformData` function a bit, look at my [fork of you plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CMYasRGQPg2D4yEKna4V?p=preview) (it looks like incorrect applying of colors, I think you can fix it, but otherwise it works).

Comment: Thanks-- Do you have any insight as to why your plnkr works in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE?

Comment: @LaissezPasser Unfortunately, I do not have any ideas. For me (osX, Firefox v. 55.0.3) it works. https://www.evernote.com/l/As1GNhCsTNdGyY7w9ffEzH1Q1oV_4lIneVYB/image.png

Comment: Interesting! It didn't work for me in Firefox on osX (will check version number) and windows 10 (56.0.2); maybe deserves further investigation. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all in this snippet:

```
function createDatesArr(start, end) {
 var arr = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++ ) {
    arr.push((i));  //      arr.push(String(i));
  }
  return arr;
}
```

using i++ won't work, as you are trying to use postfix operation not on a valid expression. You can't jump over the days using this:

```
( Fri Dec 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (+04) ) ++
```

if you are trying to get all months in diapason, you can use this simple snippet below:

```
   function createDatesArr(startDate, endDate) {
       var _start = new Date(startDate),
           _end = new Date(endDate),
           _result = [];

       while(_start < _end){
           _result.push(_start);
           // going next
           var _newDate = _start.setDate(_start.getDate() + 1);
               _start = new Date(_newDate);
       }
       return _result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide additional information to this question, that already has two good answers: You don't need that horrendous `createDatesArr` function (which was the cause of your problems here).

You can easily get an array of dates between a start date and an end date with a time scale, using `time.ticks([interval])`, which:

> Returns representative dates from the scale’s domain. The returned tick values are uniformly-spaced (mostly), have sensible values (such as every day at midnight), and are guaranteed to be within the extent of the domain.

Not only that is safer than your function, but it is also **idiomatic** D3, meaning that its purpose is easily understood by other D3 programmers.

Here is a demo using v3, which is your version. I changed the end date to 2009 instead of 2017, so we'll have less dates in the console. Check it:

```js
var startDate = new Date('2008-1-1');
var endDate = new Date('2009-6-1');
var dates = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([startDate, endDate])
  .ticks(d3.time.months, 1);

console.log(dates)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Actually, this can be even shorter, just one line, dropping the time scale and using just `d3.time.months` or `d3.time.month.range`:

```js
var dates = d3.time.month.range(new Date('2008-1-1'), new Date('2009-6-1'), 1)

console.log(dates)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank very much. Since the data for this viz will be updated continuously, but the code itself cannot be (and needs to be robust against changes to the data structure), I ended up doing it like this:
    `var startDate = d3.time.month.offset(new Date(), -108);`  
    `var endDate = new Date ();`  
    `var dates = createDatesArr(startDate, endDate);`